# Get data stored every 5 seconds by 30 sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that is stored in my table every 5 seconds

I now need to extract this data in 30 second intervals in **SQL** efficiently

**What is the best way?**

```
  Eg 12:06:23 100 and 12:06:29 300
```

The sql would find only 12:06:29

I cannot do any summating on this data

Paul

Comment: It really unclear what you are trying to do. Can you show the table schema?

Comment: Yep I will do that a bit later 

Comment: The easiest way to try and explain this is imagine you are recording the price of electricity on the market every 5 seconds but you need to pretend that you only save the data every 30 seconds? So we basically only want the price that is closest to second 0 and second 30

Comment: Is it each day (let's say when the market is opened) - `08:00:00` - in this case we can return the data in 0 and 30 seconds only?

Comment: Uh this is confusing but use the DATEADD

Comment: Let’s try diff way to explain it we can only show 2 prices per minute but we cannot guarantee having a price at 30 it may be at 29. Date add has potential I could say get latest between 0 and 30 then 30 and 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join and max if I understand you correctly.

```
Select 
   max(t1.dateTimeColumn)
   ,max(t2.dateTimeColumn)
   ,cast(t1.dateTimeColumn as date)
From
   Table t1
    left join table t2 on 
    t1.id=t2.id and t2.dateTimeColumn <= dateadd(second, -30, t1.dateTimeColumn)
Group by
   cast(t1.dateTimeColumn as date)
```